# Xamarain Forms file read permissions issue on Android. ENOENT (No such file or directory). Only happens for some users

Tags: android, xamarin

I've got a Xamarin.Forms app on the Google Play store for changing the pitch and speed of music and video. Its got a file read permissions problem on Android, but only for some users (stack trace shown below). I've set the external storage read permission:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

in the manifest.

For the majority of users, all is working correctly when selecting an audio/video file. But I'm getting notified via Rollbar https://rollbar.com/ of the file permissions issues for some users in android versions 8-11.

I'm using the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker/ plugin to browse for music/video files in my app.

Rollbar error notification from my app:

Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Kev Hlub Tu Tag Nag Hmo (Lyric).mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) ---> Android.Systems.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Stack trace:

```
Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Kev Hlub Tu Tag Nag Hmo (Lyric).mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) ---> Android.Systems.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <24e422c426e0468ca1fd74b59870ff08>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <24e422c426e0468ca1fd74b59870ff08>:0 
  at Android.Media.MediaPlayer.SetDataSource (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri) [0x00053] in <4586a87d34754df7a521e11e2fd22040>:0 
  at FormsVideoLibrary.Droid.VideoPlayerRenderer.SetSource () [0x0003e] in <01a54421e2d344a3a06c7dbb0d52b8a1>:0 
  --- End of managed Java.IO.FileNotFoundException stack trace ---
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Kev Hlub Tu Tag Nag Hmo (Lyric).mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1259)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1230)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1147)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1072)
    at crc646e83aba39dfdd46d.VideoPlayerRenderer.n_surfaceCreated(Native Method)
    at crc646e83aba39dfdd46d.VideoPlayerRenderer.surfaceCreated(VideoPlayerRenderer.java:70)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:1284)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$1.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:225)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1124)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3854)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2618)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9971)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1010)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:809)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:744)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:995)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8373)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
    ... 24 more
```

My App on Google Play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darceysoft.mavsc&hl=en&gl=US

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Cheers,

Wayne

Comment: Does the user have this error on a specific device?

Comment: Hi, it is a number of different devices from android versions 8 to 11. The majority of devices are fine though.

Comment: you get runtime Permission Checks in Android 6.0 or higher?